# Login PHP: formatting text?

Tags: php, session, authentication

i have a login system like this:

```
session_start ();
 header('Cache-Control: Private');
if(isset($_REQUEST['user']))
{

    $_SESSION['Suser']=$_REQUEST['user'];
    $_SESSION['Spsw']=$_REQUEST['psw'];
}

$user=$_SESSION['Suser'];
$user = trim($user, " ");
    $password=$_SESSION['Spsw'];
    if($user==="User" && $password==="UserPass")
    {
    }
    else
    {
       header("location: error.php");
    }
```

I wish you can login even if the username is written in all capital letters or lower case or for example in this mode: UsEr ... how do I? Thanks a lot!

Comment: lower all and compare http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strtolower.php

Comment: I would not use `$_REQUEST`....

Comment: Are you aware that you are comparing the entered username to the string `"User"`?

Comment: @Simone Cognom .. Try to mark the answers as "Accepted" (by clicking tick / check icon next to it), if that answer / solution worked for you. This is how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 1):

So simple..

use something like this;

```
if (strtolower($entered_username) == strtolower($stored_username)){
  echo("login successfull");
}else{
  echo("incorrect username");
}
```

PHP's **strtolower()** function converts letters to lowercase.

Comment: This is the only correct answer between a lot of sillyness. You need to actually use the `strtolower()` function of both sides of the comparsion.

Comment: The asker never accepts any of the answers, so I upvoted to balance the fairness of the universe.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to change the variable you receive to lowercase. You can do that using the function strtolower($str).
For example:

```
    session_start ();
 header('Cache-Control: Private');
if(isset($_REQUEST['user']))
{

    $_SESSION['Suser']=$_REQUEST['user'];
    $_SESSION['Spsw']=$_REQUEST['psw'];
}

$user=$_SESSION['Suser'];
$user = trim($user, " ");
    $password=$_SESSION['Spsw'];
    if(strtolower($user) === "user" && $password === "userpass")
    {
    }
    else
    {
       header("location: error.php");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(strtolower($user) !== "user")
 {
   header("location: error.php");
 }
```

Comment: `strtolower($password)` **Hold it right there.** Passwords should ***NEVER*** be case-insensitive.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would need to check for the right password too.